# Support for SOQL in Mule Applications having multiple workers

Tags: mule, mule-cluster

I have been working on Mule past couple of months and understand the Mule worker and load balancing if a http endpoint is hit. However, One of the use case is where I have used Salesforce connector and wrote SOQL to get the updates done on any object (let say Account). The issue is when an update is done in the Salesforce Object it brings the update message in all the three workers. This could be handled with some coding at the application side to discard the other two messages but I am looking if there is some out of the box solution where "exactly" one message is received to only one worker instead of all three. Appreciate for your response.

-$achin

Comment: Sounds more like you want batching instead of load balancing.

Comment: Hi Snickers, not batching because if two updates are done in an account I want one to worker-1 and one to worker-2. Not sure if SOQL can provide this option as that is based on pub/sub model and hence both worker should get that however as application perspective I do not want to process both the messages by both the workers.

Comment: Then a coordinator should be subscribed instead of both the workers, and that coordinator take care of this behaviour.

Comment: yeah may be..but that would introduce one more layer to manage for dev/deployment perspective. This takes my freedom to runtime change the worker count which Mule provides out of the box. Anyways for now I am going to make change in my application to handle it. I guess by design only the message should goto all the subscribers and there is nothing much I can do. thanks anyways.